# Sometimes after cleaning and redeploying 9 Patches images dont work. Have to redeploy a few times to fix

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm not sure why this is happening.. But sometimes when we have a new build, the 9 patches don't work (the actual 9 patch image gets stretched instead of being scaled properly)..

I'm not sure why this happens, but i think it happens after cleaning and creating a new build, i have to uninstall, and re-build to fix it..

I'm just worried when we release, customers might get this screen (it looks terrible).. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I've the same issue. I suppose it's a bug in the new Eclipse version. Since the recent update, I've a lot of problems :(

Comment: yeah i think it might an eclipse issue as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only 'fast' way I found on fixing that issue is renaming the nine patch drawable to a temporal name and then rename it back to it's original name.

I know it's a bit hacky but at least it works :D

Comment: Thanks for the response but it actually happens to all of the images so renaming them could take me a couple of hours :)

Comment: That's the drawback, the idea would forcing a reload of the R file, or creating a plugin that makes a clean and renames or resources files back and forth.

Comment: Could you try to rename the res folder instead?

Comment: I will try doing that next time it happens, it doesnt happen very often

Answer (score 1):

Rename any of your resource file name then refresh your project. Again rename that file to the previous name and refresh your project again. Run the project it will work fine.